# IReports SubReports Limitation

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, subreport

Is there any limitation about creating sub reports i mean 
parent--->sub----->other subs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limitation! You can go as long as you have physical space to fit data in.